# Unable to use streamchat gives error of user not able to read channel

Tags: reactjs, getstream-chat

**Error: StreamChat error code 17: GetOrCreateChannel failed with error: "User '3f5e093' with role 'user' is not allowed to perform action ReadChannel in scope 'messaging'"**
Why is this error coming for users

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Auth from "./Components/auth";
import MessagingContainer from "./Components/messagingcontainer";
import { StreamChat } from "stream-chat";
import { Chat, Channel } from "stream-chat-react";
import "@stream-io/stream-chat-css/dist/css/index.css";
import { Cookies, useCookies } from "react-cookie";
const App = () => {
     const [cookies,setCookie,removeCookie]=useCookies([`user`]);
  const [data,setData]=useState({})
  const authToken=cookies.authToken
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(authToken)
    { const tempobj={};
      const chatClient = new StreamChat('apikey');
      chatClient.connectUser(
        {
          id: cookies.user_id,
          name: cookies.Name,
        },
        authToken,
      );
      tempobj.client=chatClient;

      const channel = chatClient.channel('messaging', 'demo', {
        // add as many custom fields as you'd like
        name: 'demo',
        members: [cookies.user_id],
        
      });
      tempobj.channel=channel;
      console.log(tempobj);
      setData(tempobj);
    }
  },[])
  
  return (
    <>
      {!authToken && <Auth />}
      {authToken &&  data.client &&(
        <Chat client={data?.client} darkMode={true}>
          <Channel channel={data?.channel}>
            <MessagingContainer />
          </Channel>
        </Chat>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Stream Chat check permission system in action. Please refer to our docs to learn more: https://getstream.io/chat/docs/javascript/user_permissions/?language=javascript

You are welcome to forward your questions to support@getstream.io as well.

Kind regards,
Guilherme Cortes
Support Engineer